# How to handle session factory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

I have following bean in my configuration class:

```
@Bean
fun sessionFactory(@Autowired entityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory) :
        SessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory::class.java)
```

but it causes application fail to start.

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   userRepository defined in file [/home/m/Code/enterprise/out/production/classes/com/xxx/site/domain/user/repository/UserRepository.class]
┌─────┐
|  getSessionFactory defined in class path resource [com/xxx/site/WebMvcConfig.class]
└─────┘
```

User Repository:

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("mysql")
class UserRepository(@Autowired private val sessionFactory: SessionFactory): UserRepositoryInterface{
...
}
```

I use Spring boot 2.0.0.M4.

This problem was not occur for Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE though.

*SiteApplication.kt*

```
package com.xxx.site

import com.xxx.site.interceptor.CustomLocaleChangeInterceptor
import nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

@SpringBootApplication
class SiteApplication


@Configuration
class WebMvcConfig: WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    fun localeResolver(): LocaleResolver {
        val slr = SessionLocaleResolver()
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale("th"))
        return slr
    }

    override fun addInterceptors(registry: InterceptorRegistry?) {
        registry!!.addInterceptor(CustomLocaleChangeInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**")
    }

    @Bean
    fun layoutDialect(): LayoutDialect {
        return LayoutDialect()
    }

    @Bean
    fun sessionFactory(@Autowired entityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory) :
            SessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory::class.java)

}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(SiteApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the SessionFactory in the first place?

Comment: As I understand it caches generated SQL statements and I can use Hiberante API directly and... it was in tutorial ¯\_ツ_/¯ I'm generally new to jvm ecosystem.

Comment: The standard JPA API is all you should need. Stick to the standard.

Comment: As @JBNizet said, stick to the standard if possible. But anyway, there is a problem here which should be solved. Can you also post `WebMvcConfig`?

Comment: Thx guys. @guenhter - I've put it in my post. If you need anything else let me know.

Comment: I went with this tutorial: https://stonesoupprogramming.com/2017/07/08/kotlin-spring-security-hibernate-login/. What I've changed is gradle, latest spring boot (2.0.0.M4) and kotlin (1.1.50)